# Unifying Empires

Tags: government, royalty

I'm writing about an OC's home empire for a short bio, and I am completely baffled as to what would happen when she marries her husband, who is the heir to the throne of a different empire. Would it just become one large empire?

Comment: That's the kind of thing that is decided before the marriage is allowed.  In the case of Spain of Ferdinand and Isabella, the two states did merge.  In other cases, like the Hapsburg Empire of Charles V the components soon split up among descendants.

Comment: OC? In real life, it depends. What's the setting?

Comment: @Oldcat actually, in Spain the different kingdoms continued to be separate entities (which happened to be ruled by the same king) for several centuries. When the old king died, each "Cortes" had to approve his heir as the new King separately. Similarly, laws were different for people of the different kingdoms (one example being commerce with America being a Castillan only privilege). The kingdoms were actually merged only after Philip V of Spain and (maybe most importantly) the War of the Spanish Sucession.

Comment: There's woefully little detail in your question. With more specifics about the personalities and empires involved.  For example, are the kings very strong personalities or is one much stronger than the other? Are the two countries in a position to merge and would their respective cultures tolerate such a merge?

Comment: :)  And welcome to Worldbuilding!

Comment: Other than that, I mostly agree with Oldcat's comment... here bloodlines would be mostly "an excuse"; those benefiting from a unified empire would consider the primogenite of such a marriage heir of both empires, those opposing it would claim that "law" and "tradition" force that each empire goes to a different son, or even claim that his part of the empire has another, more legitimate, pretender.

Comment: @SJuan76 - I wasn't aware of that detail about separate crownings, but Austria and Hungary had the same thing but for all purposes were considered one empire under the Hapsburgs - to the point that Maria Theresa had to be crowned King of Hungary because a Queen could not rule.  Odd internal details of law were common enough even in countries rule by one ruler - England comes to mind, with odd laws in different areas of London for historical reasons.

Comment: I may be the only one, but what's an [OC](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/OC)?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Original character. you would think

Comment: Like has been commented before, there is too little information in the question. We even have to infer that the OC is heir to the throne of her empire. But sure, culturies/countries/empires that are not that different have been known to merge in ther past. As long as serving different thrones was the main reason that they was divided, then it is quite simple.

Comment: @Gilles It's mainly fantasy based. The setting is basically a large landmass, cut down the middle by a mountain range, with several kingdoms to the west and a large Empire to the ease.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Oldcat, [marriages of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_of_state) should be carefully negotiated beforehand. Assuming that didn't happen, consider this:

- The heir of the Empress of A and the Emperor of B might be in line for the throne of A and B. Are the rules of succession compatible? For instance, B might have a [salic succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_succession) while A is strictly based on primogeniture. If the first child is a boy, he will inherit the crowns of A and B. A girl would only inherit in A.
- As mentioned by SJuan76, having the same head of state doesn't necessarily unify empires. The technical term is [personal union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_union), and it may or may not last. Consider that [Elisabeth II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_II) is queen of the [Bahamas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bahamas#Post-World_War_II), but that doesn't make the Bahamas part of the UK.
- How strong are laws and traditions in both empires? Can a strong ruler overcome them? The [Habsburgs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_Sanction_of_1713) tried that, and unrest followed.

Summarized, empires don't merge *just* because their current rulers are married. On the other hand, that is one way how mergers can happen.